# replace zeros with NA conditionally in

Tags: r, dplyr

In the below `df`, there are only 2 farms, so each `fruit` is duplicated.  i'd like to replace zeros with `NA` as follows

```
df[df==0] <- NA
```

However, whenever there is a value for either of the fruits, such as for a `pear` at `y2019` with values `c(0, 7)`, i'd like not to replace `0`.  `dplyr` solution would be great.

sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(fruit = c("apple", "apple", "peach", "peach", "pear", "pear", "lime", "lime"),
                    farm = as.factor(c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)), 'y2019' = c(0,0,3,12,0,7,4,6), 
                    'y2018' = c(5,3,0,0,8,2,0,0),'y2017' = c(4,5,7,15,0,0,0,0) )
> df
  fruit farm y2019 y2018 y2017
1 apple    1     0     5     4
2 apple    2     0     3     5
3 peach    1     3     0     7
4 peach    2    12     0    15
5  pear    1     0     8     0
6  pear    2     7     2     0
7  lime    1     4     0     0
8  lime    2     6     0     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("y20")), ~ if (any(. != 0)) . else NA_real_) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 5
#   fruit farm  y2019 y2018 y2017
#   <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 apple 1        NA     5     4
# 2 apple 2        NA     3     5
# 3 peach 1         3    NA     7
# 4 peach 2        12    NA    15
# 5 pear  1         0     8    NA
# 6 pear  2         7     2    NA
# 7 lime  1         4    NA    NA
# 8 lime  2         6    NA    NA
```

Comment: thx, say i had `NA` instead of zeros in the original `df` and wanted just replace **relevant** 'NA' with 0?  would this be the right syntax `~ if(is.na(any(.))) 0`? it freezes `R` on me...

Comment: (1) `any(is.na(.))` seems better than `is.na(any(.))`. (2) "relevant" sounds subjective, do you have something more concrete? Is there something in this answer that doesn't do what you have in your question? (The 0,7 pair is preserved) (3) Replacing 0`s` with `NA`s or `NA`s with `0`s it effectively the same thing (`==0` vs `is.na`), can you adapt this answer to whichever direction you intend to go?

Comment: exactly, trying to adapt as looking at your answer i realized having a chunk of redundant code converting `NA`s to `0`s first. this `df%>% group_by(fruit) %>%  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if((any(is.na(.))) 0 ))` throws an error

Comment: Your parens are mis-matched (well, mis-placed) and you need an `else`. Try `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if (any(is.na(.))) 0 else .))`