# Replace NA conditionally

Tags: r, dplyr

*this an augmented version of my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815630/replace-zeros-with-na-conditionally-in) as i could not clearly explain it through the comments*

There are only 2 `farms`, so each `fruit` is duplicated in the below `df`. i'd like to replace `NA` with `0` only if there is a value for either of the fruits, such as for a `pear` at `y2019` with values `c(NA, 7)`, i'd like to output `c(0,7)` instead.

*sample data:*

```
df <- data.frame(fruit = c("apple", "apple", "peach", "peach", "pear", "pear", "lime", "lime"),
                 farm = as.factor(c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)), 'y2019' = c(NA,NA,3,12,NA,7,4,6), 
                 'y2018' = c(5,3,NA,NA,8,2,NA,NA),'y2017' = c(4,5,7,15,NA,NA,1,NA))

> df
  fruit farm y2019 y2018 y2017
1 apple    1    NA     5     4
2 apple    2    NA     3     5
3 peach    1     3    NA     7
4 peach    2    12    NA    15
5  pear    1    NA     8    NA
6  pear    2     7     2    NA
7  lime    1     4    NA     1
8  lime    2     6    NA    NA
```

this is close

```
df %>%
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if (any(is.na(.))) 0  else .)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

but :

1. `7` gets wiped out in `pear` producing `c(0,0)`.
2. i'd like to leave `NA` in when both farms are `NA`

   ```
     #A tibble: 8 x 5
      fruit farm  y2019 y2018 y2017
      <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1 apple 1         0     5     4
    2 apple 2         0     3     5
    3 peach 1         3     0     7
    4 peach 2        12     0    15
    5 pear  1         0     8     0
    6 pear  2         0     2     0
    7 lime  1         4     0     0
    8 lime  2         6     0     0
   ```

*desired outcome:*

```
> df
  fruit farm y2019 y2018 y2017
1 apple    1    NA     5     4
2 apple    2    NA     3     5
3 peach    1     3    NA     7
4 peach    2    12    NA    15
5  pear    1     0     8    NA
6  pear    2     7     2    NA
7  lime    1     4    NA     1
8  lime    2     6    NA     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if(any(!is.na(.))) 
                replace(., is.na(.), 0)  else .)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  fruit farm  y2019 y2018 y2017
#  <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 apple 1        NA     5     4
#2 apple 2        NA     3     5
#3 peach 1         3    NA     7
#4 peach 2        12    NA    15
#5 pear  1         0     8    NA
#6 pear  2         7     2    NA
#7 lime  1         4    NA     1
#8 lime  2         6    NA     0
```

So we `replace` `NA` to 0 only if there is any value in the group which is not `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace_na` from `tidyr` if there are `any` non-NA elements to replace with 0 or `else` return the value

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if(any(!is.na(.))) replace_na(., 0) else .)) %>%
   ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  fruit farm  y2019 y2018 y2017
#  <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 apple 1        NA     5     4
#2 apple 2        NA     3     5
#3 peach 1         3    NA     7
#4 peach 2        12    NA    15
#5 pear  1         0     8    NA
#6 pear  2         7     2    NA
#7 lime  1         4    NA     1
#8 lime  2         6    NA     0
```

---

or another option without `if/else` by having two logical expressions in `replace` after doing the group by 'fruit'

```
df %>%
     group_by(fruit) %>%
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
           ~ replace(., sum(!is.na(.)) > 0 & is.na(.), 0)))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   fruit [4]
#  fruit farm  y2019 y2018 y2017
#  <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 apple 1        NA     5     4
#2 apple 2        NA     3     5
#3 peach 1         3    NA     7
#4 peach 2        12    NA    15
#5 pear  1         0     8    NA
#6 pear  2         7     2    NA
#7 lime  1         4    NA     1
#8 lime  2         6    NA     0
```